# error in sum the value in binary search tree

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

How can I sum the values that inside bst (binary search tree)
I tried this code but gave me error

```
def total(bst):
    total = 0
    bst = BST()
    node = bst._root
    if node == None:
        total = 0
    if node._right is not None and node._left is not None:
        total = total + node._right + node._left
    elif node._right is not None and node._left is None:
        total = total + node._right
    else:
        total = total + node._left
    return total
```

the error that I get it:

```
if node._right is not None and node._left is not None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_right'
```

Also, I tried this way it gives me zero

```
bst.comparision = 0
x= bst.comparision
return x
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want an `elif`?

```
def total(bst):
    total = 0
    bst = BST()
    node = bst._root
    if node == None:
        total = 0
    # elif, not if?
    elif node._right is not None and node._left is not None:
        total = total + node._right + node._left
    elif node._right is not None and node._left is None:
        total = total + node._right
    else:
        total = total + node._left
    return total
```

As your code is written, if `node == None`, then you set `total = 0` and immediately go on the check `node._right` (which doesn't exist because `None` doesn't have a `_right` attribute)

---

Also, as an aside, `if node is None` is generally preferred to `if node == None` since `None` is a singleton.

Comment: I do it but gives me zero!!